# Освежающий каркаде или освежающее каркаде?

Tags: согласование, род

Скажите, как правильно: *освежающий каркаде* или *освежающее каркаде*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Орфографический словарь [указывает](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UElrf.png), что оба рода (м. и с.) равнодопустимы.
Тем не менее в литературе в подавляющем большинстве случаев используется мужской род  (видимо, по аналогии с мужским родом слова "чай").